# How to connect Zebra ZT-411 with react native expo?

Tags: react-native, zebra-printers

I am trying to connect and print barcode sticker from Zebra ZT-411 printer, but can not find any working solution. Also I am new to mobile app development. Can someone help he here? I have tried https://github.com/anmoljain10 this package but its not compatible with my react native version which is v18.1.0. Is there any other packages I can use?

When I am using:-

> npm i react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer

This is the error showing:-

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sq_sticker@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.1" from react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer@1.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer
npm ERR!   react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer@"^1.0.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\zihan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.       

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zihan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-31T03_30_38_132Z-debug-0.log
```

If I use:-

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer

Then it installs the package without any problem but when I am trying to use any function from this package it says the function can not be found.

Here I am trying to use a function:-

```
import RNZebraBluetoothPrinter from 'react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer';

RNZebraBluetoothPrinter.enableBluetooth().then((res) => {
        //do something with res
      })
```

And here is the error:-

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enableBluetooth')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enableBluetooth')
```

Comment: can you share the right version of react native because the latest version is 0.71 but you mentioned 18.1.0. What is your error when you use https://github.com/anmoljain10/react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer can you place some examples?

Comment: Hello @KirillNovikov thank your for your response. Please check my question now, I have edited it with all the required information.

Comment: were you able to fix that issue?

Comment: @GabrielLam I bypassed it using my server which is running on windows. I could not connect native with zebra printer so I sent my request and data from react native to node(server) and from node there are many available solutions to connect with Zebra ZT-411

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are facing a compatibility issue with your React Native version and the react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer package. This is a common problem when library versions are not aligned with your project's React Native version. I faced a similar issue and managed to find a workaround.

I have created a solution and documented it on GitHub. My repository is a modified version of an existing library, adapted to work with newer versions of React Native. You can find the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-zebra-printer-qv

To implement this, please follow the tutorial I've created, which is available on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXbseqogkMQ. This tutorial mainly focuses on setting up the Android package, as I've made adjustments to the library to avoid editing in node_modules.

If you encounter a 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined' error, it's likely due to incorrect importing or a mismatch in the package version.

Additionally, if you're looking to print simple text like 'hello world' or use ZPL/CPL files, the same package can be used. Here's a snippet for printing:

```html
RNZebraBluetoothPrinter.print(deviceAddress, zpl).then((res) => {
    // Handle response
});
```